# Cached Logons Count - Registry

Tags: networking, windows-registry, login

In the registry, I have a cached logons count of 10. Does this mean that I can logon 10 times without the Domain Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Cached Logons Count in registry defines how many logins should be cached locally, and thus allow you to login if you can't reach your DC.

With default configuration cached logins never expire.

Check out [Microsoft Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/instan/2011/12/06/cached-logons-and-cachedlogonscount/) for further explanation

Comment: Okay. Follow up question: Do cached login credentials ever expire?

Comment: No, using default configuration cached logins never expire

Comment: Please quote all relevant information from your link.